# Make URI Segment Parameters Optional

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

I am developing an application in CodeIgniter that will have a database of articles.  I want to be able to filter the articles by their type(article, opinion, review, media) and then also sort by either date, views, or number of comments.  I get these parameters through the URI.  I want to be able to dynamically convert these URI's to the script's variables so that any combination of parms is possible, except more than one type or more than one sort.  For example, a URI may contain a type, but no sort... Or it may contain a sort but no type... Or it could contain both or none.  This is how my URI's look right now:

```
articles/type:media/sort:date-desc
articles/sort:comments-asc
articles/sort:views-desc
... etc.
```

This is the current script I have:

```
$uri = 'type:media/sort:views-desc';
$uri = explode('/', $uri);

$allowed_types = array('article', 'review', 'opinion', 'media');
        $allowed_sorts = array('date-asc', 'date-desc', 'views-asc', 'views-desc', 'comments-asc', 'comments-desc');        

        if(count($uri) > 0){

            for($i=0;$i<=count($args);$i++){

                $argument = explode(':', $args[$i]);

                if($argument[0] == 'type'){

                    if(in_array($argument[$i], $allowed_types)){

                        $type = $argument[1];

                    }

                } else if($argument[0] == 'sort'){

                    if(in_array($argument[$i], $allowed_sorts)){

                        $sort_by = explode('-', $argument[1]);
                        $sort_by_what = $sort_by[0];
                        $sort_by_how = $sort_by[1];

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        show_error('Type: '.$type.'... Sort By: '.$sort_by_what.'-'.$sort_by_how);
```

I am currently getting a few errors that say the three argument vars $type, $sort_by_what, $sort_by_how are not defined and also undefined offset: 1.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variables outside their scope. If you want to use them in a scope, make sure they are declared there.

Try adding:

```
$sort_by = "" ;
$sort_by_what = "" ;
$sort_by_how = "" ;
```

Outside the if condition clause.

I'd also suggest you check for the size of the array returned by the explode call, to make sure it's not empty. I think this is causing the out-of-bounds error (undefined offset: 1)

So, the code should look like:

```
    $uri = 'type:media/sort:views-desc';
$uri = explode('/', $uri);

$sort_by = "";
$sort_by_what = "";
$sort_by_how = "";
$allowed_types = array('article', 'review', 'opinion', 'media');
$allowed_sorts = array('date-asc', 'date-desc', 'views-asc', 'views-desc', 'comments-asc', 'comments-desc');

if (count($args) > 0) {

  for ($i = 0; $i <= count($args); $i++) {

    $argument = explode(':', $args[$i]);
    if (count($argument) > 0) {


      if ($argument[0] == 'type') {

        if (in_array($argument[$i], $allowed_types)) {

          $type = $argument[1];
        }
      } else if ($argument[0] == 'sort') {
        if (in_array($argument[$i], $allowed_sorts)) {

          $sort_by = explode('-', $argument[1]);
          if (count($sort_by) > 0) {
            $sort_by_what = $sort_by[0];
            $sort_by_how = $sort_by[1];
          } else {
            show_error("Can't parse sorting parameters!");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  show_error('Type: ' . $type . '... Sort By: ' . $sort_by_what . '-' . $sort_by_how);
}
```

I don't know if this is a snippet of the code, or the whole code, but where did the variable `$args` come from ?